# Is semaphore usage in this solution is correct?

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

**Problem:** 
I have to increment x1 and x2 variable which should be done by separate threads and next increment of both variables should not be called until previous increment of both variable is not completed.

[image: Problem]

**Proposed Solution:** 
Initialize 4 semaphore and invoke separate threads for separate increment of variable. 2 semaphores for passing message to threads for start incrementing and 2 semaphores for passing message to main thread that incrementation is completed. Main thread will wait for semaphore posting from both child threads showing incrementation of both variable is done, then main thread will pass message to both child threads allowing further incrementing.

*this one currently working fine for me. But, can one one suggest better solution? Or, can anyone point out problem in this solution?*
Any help will be greatly appreciated? Thanks in advance.

Solution Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

//Threads
pthread_t pth1,pth2;

//Values to calculate
int x1 = 0, x2 = 0;

sem_t c1,c2,c3,c4;

void *threadfunc1(void *parm)
{
    for (;;) {
        x1++;
        sem_post(&c1);
        sem_wait(&c3);
    }
    return NULL ;
}

void *threadfunc2(void *parm)
{
    for (;;) {
        x2++;
        sem_post(&c2);
        sem_wait(&c4);
    }
    return NULL ;
}

int main () {
    sem_init(&c1, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&c2, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&c3, 0, 0);
    sem_init(&c4, 0, 0);
    pthread_create(&pth1, NULL, threadfunc1, "foo");
    pthread_create(&pth2, NULL, threadfunc2, "foo");
    sem_wait(&c1);
    sem_wait(&c2);
    sem_post(&c3);
    sem_post(&c4);
    int loop = 0;
    while (loop < 8) {
        // iterated as a step
        loop++;
        printf("Initial   : x1 = %d, x2 = %d\n", x1, x2);
        sem_wait(&c1);
        sem_wait(&c2);
        printf("Final   : x1 = %d, x2 = %d\n", x1, x2);
        sem_post(&c3);
        sem_post(&c4);
    }
    sem_wait(&c1);
    sem_wait(&c2);
    sem_destroy(&c1);
    sem_destroy(&c2);
    sem_destroy(&c3);
    sem_destroy(&c4);
    printf("Result   : x1 = %d, x2 = %d\n", x1, x2);
    pthread_cancel(pth1);
    pthread_cancel(pth2);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Only problem i could figure out, sem_post and sem_wait is time consuming..

Comment: I'm assuming this is the sanitized example, and that the real program is doing more than just incrementing counters?  In particular, the sole purpose of threads is to let you do two things at once.  Intentionally locking them down into such lockstep form defeats their entire purpose.

Comment: yes, in big picture, x2 might be dependent on x1, which needs latest x1 value at particular step solve to be calculated. It is a kind of solver doing step solve at each iteration @CortAmmon

Comment: Why not just run x1 and then x2 in a single thread?  What benefit are you trying to achieve with the multthreading?

Comment: yes i completely agree with you. But if calculations are in millions, then this overhead might overcome the time. Hence i am moving ahead this way. But i am looking for any other way to pause the thread and invoke it again with some king of signal like SIGSTOP and SIGINT for processes @CortAmmon

Comment: x1 and x2 are symbolizing set of big calculations to be done different threads. and next iteration will be called after completion of single iterations from all threads. @CortAmmon

Comment: Ahh, so x1 is really a set of many paralellizable tasks, x1a, x1b, x1c, x1d... all of which must be completed before x2 can start?

Comment: Set of X1 and set of X2 will go parallel for one iteration.. wait for completion of current iteration and then again for next iteration and so on.. @CortAmmon

Comment: sem_post and sem_wait is working perfectly for the code. But in bigger simulations, it is taking lot of time depending on the number of threads and number of semaphore. So Is there any possibility to pause a thread from inside self thread and resume it back after passing a signal from other thread in C Programming? @CortAmmon

Comment: Use mutexes and condition variables (like I did in the answer I just posted).  they **are** C's version of passing a signal to another thread, so they are your best bet.
Fundamentally, pausing and unpausing threads is a slow process because the operating system HAS to get involved.

Comment: Thanks @CortAmmon, i will try the same and will revert back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a bunch of threads to do x1 things, pausing them, then having a bunch of  threads do x2 things, consider a threadpool.  A threadpool is a bunch of threads which sit idle until you have work for them to do, then they unpause and do the work.

An advantage of this system is that it uses condition variables and mutexes rather than semaphores.  On many systems, mutexes are faster that semaphores (because they are more limited).

```
// a task is an abstract class describing "something that can be done" which
// can be put in a work queue
class Task
{
    public:
        virtual void run() = 0;
};

// this could be made more Object Oriented if desired... this is just an example.
// a work queue 
struct WorkQueue
{
    std::vector<Task*>  queue; // you must hold the mutex to access the queue
    bool                finished; // if this is set to true, threadpoolRun starts exiting
    pthread_mutex_t     mutex;
    pthread_cond_t      hasWork; // this condition is signaled if there may be more to do
    pthread_cond_t      doneWithWork; // this condition is signaled if the work queue may be empty
};

void threadpoolRun(void* queuePtr)
{
    // the argument to threadpoolRun is always a WorkQueue*
    WorkQueue& workQueue= *dynamic_cast<WorkQueue*>(queuePtr);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&workQueue.mutex);

    // precondition: every time we start this while loop, we have to have the
    // mutex.
    while (!workQueue.finished) {
        // try to get work.  If there is none, we wait until someone signals hasWork
        if (workQueue.queue.empty()) {
            // empty.  Wait until another thread signals that there may be work
            // but before we do, signal the main thread that the queue may be empty
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&workQueue.doneWithWOrk);
            pthread_cond_wait(&workQueue.hasWork, &workQueue.mutex);
        } else {
            // there is work to be done.  Grab the task, release the mutex (so that
            // other threads can get things from the work queue), and start working!
            Task* myTask = workQueue.queue.back();
            workQueue.queue.pop_back(); // no one else should start this task
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&workQueue.mutex);

            // now that other threads can look at the queue, take our time
            // and complete the task.
            myTask->run();

            // re-acquire the mutex, so that we have it at the top of the while
            // loop (where we need it to check workQueue.finished)
            pthread_mutex_lock(&workQueue.mutex);
        }
    }
}

// Now we can define a bunch of tasks to do your particular problem
class Task_x1a
: public Task
{
    public:
        Task_x1a(int* inData)
        : mData(inData)
        { }

        virtual void run()
        {
            // do some calculations on mData
        }
    private:
        int*  mData;
};

class Task_x1b
: public Task
{ ... }

class Task_x1c
: public Task
{ ... }

class Task_x1d
: public Task
{ ... }

class Task_x2a
: public Task
{ ... }

class Task_x2b
: public Task
{ ... }

class Task_x2c
: public Task
{ ... }

class Task_x2d
: public Task
{ ... }

int main()
{
    // bet you thought you'd never get here!
    static const int numberOfWorkers = 4; // this tends to be either the number of CPUs
                                          // or CPUs * 2
    WorkQueue workQueue; // create the workQueue shared by all threads
    pthread_mutex_create(&workQueue.mutex);
    pthread_cond_create(&workQueue.hasWork);
    pthread_cond_create(&workQueue.doneWithWork);
    pthread_t workers[numberOfWorkers];
    int data[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWorkers; i++)
        pthread_create(&pth1, NULL, &threadpoolRun, &workQueue);

    // now all of the workers are sitting idle, ready to do work
    // give them the X1 tasks to do
    {
        Task_x1a    x1a(data);
        Task_x1b    x1b(data);
        Task_x1c    x1c(data);
        Task_x1d    x1d(data);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&workQueue.mutex);
        workQueue.queue.push_back(x1a);
        workQueue.queue.push_back(x1b);
        workQueue.queue.push_back(x1c);
        workQueue.queue.push_back(x1d);

        // now that we've queued up a bunch of work, we have to signal the
        // workers that the work is available
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&workQueue.hasWork);

        // and now we wait until the workers finish
        while(!workQueue.queue.empty())
            pthread_cond_wait(&workQueue.doneWithWork);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&workQueue.mutex);
    }
    {
        Task_x2a    x2a(data);
        Task_x2b    x2b(data);
        Task_x2c    x2c(data);
        Task_x2d    x2d(data);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&workQueue.mutex);
        workQueue.queue.push_back(x2a);
        workQueue.queue.push_back(x2b);
        workQueue.queue.push_back(x2c);
        workQueue.queue.push_back(x2d);

        // now that we've queued up a bunch of work, we have to signal the
        // workers that the work is available
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&workQueue.hasWork);

        // and now we wait until the workers finish
        while(!workQueue.queue.empty())
            pthread_cond_wait(&workQueue.doneWithWork);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&workQueue.mutex);
    }

    // at the end of all of the work, we want to signal the workers that they should
    // stop.  We do so by setting workQueue.finish to true, then signalling them
    pthread_mutex_lock(&workQueue.mutex);
    workQueue.finished = true;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&workQueue.hasWork);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&workQueue.mutex);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&workQueue.mutex);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&workQueue.hasWork);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&workQueue.doneWithWork);
    return data[0];
}
```

Major notes:

- If you have more tasks than CPUs, making extra threads is just more bookkeeping for the CPU.  The threadpool accepts any number of tasks, and then works on them with the most efficient number of CPUs possible.
- If there is way more work than CPUs (like 4 CPUs and 1000 tasks), then this system is very very efficient.  Mutex lock/unlock is the cheapest thread synchronization you will get short of a lockfree queue (which is probably way more work than it is worth).  If you have a bunch of tasks, it will just grab them one at a time.
- If your tasks are terribly tiny (like your increment example above), you can easily modify the threadPool to grab multiple Tasks at once, then work them serially.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your program is that you are synchronizing your threads to run in lockstep with each other. In each thread, at each iteration, a counter is incremented, and then two synchronization primitives are called. So, more than half the time in the loop body is spent on synchronization.

In your program, the counters really have nothing to do with each other, so they really should run independently of each other, which means each thread could actually do actual computing during their iterations rather than mostly synchronizing.

For the output requirements, you can allow each thread to put each sub-calculation into an array that the main thread can read from. The main thread waits for each thread to completely finish, and can then read from each array to create your output.

```
void *threadfunc1(void *parm)
{
    int *output = static_cast<int *>(parm);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        x1++;
        output[i] = x1;
    }
    return NULL ;
}

void *threadfunc2(void *parm)
{
    int *output = static_cast<int *>(parm);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        x2++;
        output[i] = x2;
    }
    return NULL ;
}

int main () {
    int out1[10];
    int out2[10];
    pthread_create(&pth1, NULL, threadfunc1, out1);
    pthread_create(&pth2, NULL, threadfunc2, out2);
    pthread_join(pth1, NULL);
    pthread_join(pth2, NULL);
    int loop = 0;
    while (loop < 9) {
        // iterated as a step
        loop++;
        printf("Final   : x1 = %d, x2 = %d\n", out1[loop], out2[loop]);
    }
    printf("Result   : x1 = %d, x2 = %d\n", out1[9], out2[9]);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Looping to 10?  8k, or whatever L1 cache size in ints is, would be better.

Comment: @MartinJames: I was following the output shown in the question. The asker's own code only looped until 8.

Comment: Thanks @jxh. But as i understood by looking at your code, your calculating and saving it independently. But in bigger picture, x2 might be dependent on x1, which needs latest x1 value at particular step solve to be calculated.

Comment: @Vishwadeep: Yes, the text of my solution states that this solution is in the context of the program you provided.