# Is there a better way instead of while(1) in c for waiting?

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

Is there a better way instead of `while(1)` in c? My concern is to wait in the code. and move further if work is done.

Like, 
in some thread

```
    while (cond == 0) {
     // wait
    }
```

From some other thread, `cond` variable made `1`, then thread can move further..

I want to remove this infinite while condition. Using semaphore signal is taking time while posting and receiving signal. 
Sample program I asked it in my previous question: [Is semaphore usage in this solution is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395459/is-semaphore-usage-in-this-solution-is-correct)

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "using semaphore signal is taking time"?

Comment: I hope you mean `cond == 0`

Comment: when i am doing sem_post(&c); and sem_wait(&c); this is taking more time then running the code in a sequential mode.. i am dividing calculations in a batch for different threads, but semaphore posting and receiving is making it more slower than sequential code @jxh

Comment: yes @flyx, sorry i missed it, it is cond == 0.

Comment: If you serialize all the calculations done by your threads, it will run slower than doing it all in one thread. You will have to show a small sample of your program that illustrates the lack of speed up that you are expecting.

Comment: @jxh problem is if i am using while(1) to wait, then my processor is used used up very fast, if i am using semaphore, then it is becoming slow.. Anyhow results are correct? but task is not achieved..

Comment: There is probably a logical error in your code, but there is no way to diagnose without seeing how you have structured your program.

Comment: @jxh  Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395459/is-semaphore-usage-in-this-solution-is-correct 
In this program, if i do sequentially x1++ and x2++ will be much more faster than semaphore. This is a kind of problem i am struggling.

Comment: Doing what you're describing will to little besides give the thread synchro objects a nice work-out. (which may be the point of the exercise to begin with).

Comment: The problem with your program is that you are synchronizing after every iteration, and in each iteration, more than half the work is synchronization itself. Instead of trying to force each thread to run in lockstep with each other, just divide the work in a way so that each thread gets half the work, and let them run until they are finished.

Comment: what actually you are suggesting @jxh?? Please i am little new to threading? Can you please elaborate.

Comment: What did I say that is unclear? Don't synchronize at each iteration, synchronize after all the iterations are done.

Comment: This is the problem @jhx , i have to divide it, because calculations are in millions and next step is dependent on previous calculations.. This is kind on initial value problem for solver..

Comment: Sorry @jhx, i read your updated comment late. I got your idea. But i had told my problem in previous comment

Comment: If the next step is dependent on the previous calculations that much, maybe the problem isn't suited for multithreading?

Comment: @tangrs Suppose i have millions of variables to be calculated, which might be interdependent on each other. After defining their initial value, i can calculate all of them on different threads. But for next step solve (means next iteration) i can calculate all of them like similar to previous way but with new updated values. So, i can use threads for calculating lot of calculations? this is my basic idea to implement. Please suggest where i can improve?

Comment: I would not have one thread per variable.

Comment: Kernel synchro, using semas, events, mutex work fine as long as the threads often perform blocking operations and/or the tasks signaled across the threads are sufficiently lengthy that the time spend in the synchro is insignificant.  If you don't/cannot design your data/code in such ways, then sure, the time spent on synchro will be excessive.

Comment: @jxh you can see it 1 million variables per thread.. similarly for 10 million i will have 10 threads.. This i had posted as an example...

Comment: @MartinJames Are you suggesting, if my calculations are more enough than time spent of synchronization, then only i can get the benefit? Please can you give me basic idea, where i am missing? I had posted my example code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395459/is-semaphore-usage-in-this-solution-is-correct

Comment: Does each variable's value use all 10 million values to compute its next value, or does it mostly use the 1 million that the current thread is managing?

Comment: Not each, but mostly... Like x1++ that is x1 = x1+1 value is repeated in every iteration.. similarly it can be x1 = p+q; where p and q values are from previous loop..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you describe, a condition variable seems to be the more appropriate solution. See [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConditionVariables).

Comment: i can try the link @flyx Thanks