# Is there any possibility to pause a thread from inside self thread and resume it back after passing a signal from other thread in C Programming?

Tags: c, multithreading

**Problem**: Invoke a thread, which by default will be paused. It should resume after passing a signal from other thread, and perform the task.

Semaphore and pthread condition i had already tried and they are taking lot of time, if i have to pass condition signal very fast in a loop. Is there any other way? or any way to pause/resume a thread in C Programming?

Operating System: Linux

Comment: Yes there is: pthreads mutexes and condition variables.  That is the correct way to do it.  Why are those such an overhead problem?  Usually if they are not fast enough, it means you should modify your algorithm to use them less often (like checking every 10 items instead of checking every 1 item).

What is your algorithm doing?  We may be able to help improve the algorithsm.

Comment: Thanks @CortAmmon. Please help. This is exact my problem: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18395459/is-semaphore-usage-in-this-solution-is-correct

Comment: If you're using condition variables correctly (ie. dependent on a condition, not used as a poor man's event), you shouldn't have much of a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use select/poll/epoll and wait with it on [signalfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html).

Comment: thanks @zoska , can you please provide any simple example on its usage. I am little new for threading.